# SQL Parameters in C# aren't working as expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, parameters

I think I'm making a fairly amateur mistake somewhere here, but I can't get SQL Parameters to reliably work in C#. Consider the following code:

```
        protected string[] Query(string dataToFind, string tableName, string fieldToCheck, string fieldToReturn)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT " + fieldToReturn + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + fieldToCheck " = '" + dataToFind "'";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
etc...
```

This executes as you would expect, returning the `fieldToReturn` from the table `tableName`. However, I understand that this is vulnerably to SQL injections, and that the correct way to avoid this is to use parameters. So I change my code to the following:

```
protected string[] Query(string dataToFind, string tableName, string fieldToCheck, string fieldToReturn)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[4];
        parameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@dataToFind", dataToFind);
        parameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@name", tableName);
        parameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@fieldToCheck", fieldToCheck);
        parameters[3] = new SqlParameter("@fieldToReturn", fieldToReturn);

        SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        command.CommandText = "SELECT @fieldToReturn FROM @tableName WHERE @fieldToCheck = @dataToReturn";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
etc...
```

If I have 3 matches in my database, the first code example returns 3 matches. The second code returns 0 results?!

Am I being stupid and missing something obvious?

Comment: Parameters are not suitable for choosing tables or columns. Take a look into ef or another ORM to bypass that.

Comment: You cannot use parameters for the Field and Table names.

Comment: Really you shouldn't be embedding SQL in your executable anyway.  Try using stored procedures that can execute sections of script on a selective basis.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I'm just experimenting with all of this at the moment. It's working now, but in the future I will look into stored procedures :)

Comment: @Westie: Could you perhaps elaborate on that? A simple "don't do this or that" doesn't really help with understanding why this should or shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Yes - apologies.  [This explains what embedded code is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL).  However it's considered bad practice to embed like this as the code is less accessible and your code will need to be (at the very least) examined to ensure that any changes to your database layer ([see n-tier development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-tier)) do not adversely affect your code (business layer).  By using stored procedures in your database layer you can *usually* make minor modifications to the procedure without having to edit and recompile your application...

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are:

```
@dataToFind
@name
@fieldToCheck
@fieldToReturn
```

Your Query's CommandText has:

```
@fieldToReturn
@tableName
@fieldToCheck
@dataToReturn
```

These do not match. They must match in order to be properly applied.